# Is there a way to change ID of a Tkinter Treeview Item

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating an app in which I will have a Library containing several Books, each Book containing multiple Sections and each section containing multiple Pages. To visually show the library I am using TreeView widget. The problem is that the whole algorithm works on IDs of Books, Sections and Pages:

The ID of a Book is the title of the book after replacing spaces with "_".

The ID of a Section is combination of the ID of Book it's in and title of Section.

The ID of a Page is the combination of the ID of Section it's in and the title of Page.

And now I want to change the title of Section and Book but in order to do so, I would have to delete the Section and insert a new section with a new ID and also I would have to change the IDs of Pages in the Section. Is there a simpler way to do it (possibly without using loops)
Here are the codes I am currently using:

```
def rename(self, old_id, new_title):
    book_id = self.tv.parent(old_id)
    book_text = self.tv.item(book_id, "text")
    new_id = f"{book_text.replace(' ', '_')}|{new_title.replace(' ', '_')}"
    ind = self.tv.index(old_id)
    pages = self.tv.get_children(old_id)
    self.tv.insert(book_id, ind, new_id, text=new_title, tags=new_id)
    for page in pages:
        page_text = self.tv.item(page, "text")
        child_new_id = f"{book_text.replace(' ', '_')}|{new_title.replace(' ', '_')}|{page_text.replace(' ', '_')}"
        self.tv.delete(page)
        self.tv.insert(new_id, END, child_new_id, text=new_title, tags=child_new_id)
    self.tv.delete(old_id)
```